# PhpStorm warns about Object methods in Vue component when using TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, phpstorm, webstorm

When creating Vue components using TypeScript (via the `lang="ts"` attribute of the script tag), PhpStorm (version 2021.2.2) shows a warning about any methods of the native JavaScript `Object` as "Unresolved function or method", e.g.:

```
<template>
  ...
</template>

<script lang="ts">
const v = Object.values({ a: 'a', b: 'b' });
</script>
```

Results in:

[image: Screenshot of PhpStorm highlighting Object.values as undefined]

How can PhpStorm (or WebStorm) be configured to recognise `Object` as the native JS ES6+ `Object`?

*(For reference, Cmd + clicking on `Object` jumps to `lib.es5.d.ts` so it's assuming the wrong version of JavaScript. However, under Languages & Frameworks > JavasScript, the version is already set to ECMAScript 6+)*

Comment: Take a look at this [github issue which mentions your exact problem](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/1431#issuecomment-536378401) `The script lang=ts showing misleading errors in .vue files`

Comment: Are you not getting errors when compiling? Is the problem only with the IDE? What are your options under "More actions..." in your screenshot.

Comment: @JuanMendes - the github issue seems to be a little different, as it's talking about problems with references on the vue instance, rather a generic JS version mismatch in the IDE.
Re. errors when compiling - no, there are no errors, and the code executes fine. It's just the IDE that's at fault.

Comment: If your typescript configuration is wrong (and it seems that it is), compiler will show errors as well. Did you try enabling the compiler service in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript**, BTW?

Comment: @lena - yes, Typescript language service is enabled. The compiler does not show any errors - it's purely the IDE that highlights it as a problem.

Answer (score 1):

`Object.values()` is [part of ES2017](https://tc39.es/ecma262/2017/#sec-object.values).
Make sure to either set `"target"` to `"esnext"` or add `"esnext"` to `"lib": []` in `tsconfig.json`

[image]

Comment: I'm getting the problematic behaviour on 2021.2.2 - so it must be a configuration issue...

Comment: I've added a better screenshot and the exact error message wording now.

Comment: "Works for me" is not really an answer, is it?

Comment: ctrl+click on `Object` - where does it jump to?

Comment: @lena - It jumps to `lib.es5.d.ts` so it's obviously assuming that version of JS for some reason.

Comment: what is the `"target"` value in your `tsconfig.json`? Try setting it to `esnext` - does it help?